# Jquery - Change color of link

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
     <div id="libdiv" class = "libraryheader ">
         <a href="#"  class="libraryheader" id="videoLink"  /> Videos </a>
         | <a  href="#" class="libraryheader"  id="articleLink" /> Articles </a> 
         | <a href="#" id="newsLink" class="libraryheader"  /> News </a>
     </div>
```

When I click on a link, I like to I like the color of the link to turn gold while other links to be grey.

```
    .libraryheader
     {

        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        color: #4F5A5E;  /* grey color */ 
        text-decoration: none;
     }

    .libraryheaderselected
    {

      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 24px;
      color: gold;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

What is happening is that when I select it links, they turn gold but when I selected another link, the prevously selected remains as gold and does not turn grey. I like only the selected link to be gold. All others should default to grey.

Here is the code I have:

```
 $('#libdiv a').click(function () {

            $(this).removeClass('libraryheaderselected');
            $('#videoLink').addClass('libraryheader');
            $('#articleLink').addClass('libraryheader');
            $('#newsLink').addClass('libraryheader');

            $(this).addClass('libraryheaderselected');             


        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's **no need to add or remove the `libraryheader` class from any of the links.** HTML elements can have more than one class at a time. That means all your links can keep the `libraryheader` class, while you simply toggle a secondary class (`selected`, for example) that specifies their text color.

So all you need for your JS is this:

```
$('#libdiv a').click(function () {
    $('#libdiv a.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Also, your CSS is redundant. All you need is this:

```
 .libraryheader
 {

    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #4F5A5E;  /* grey color */ 
    text-decoration: none;
 }

.libraryheader.selected
{
    color: gold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
$('#libdiv a').click(function () {
   $('#libdiv a').removeClass('libraryheaderselected');
   $('#videoLink').addClass('libraryheader');
   $('#articleLink').addClass('libraryheader');
   $('#newsLink').addClass('libraryheader');
   $(this).addClass('libraryheaderselected');  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily and with less hassle using

```
$('#libdiv a').click(function () {
    // Toggle the two classes on the clicked item. Since all items start with
    // just the class libraryheader, this will remove it and add the selected
    $(this).toggleClass("libraryheader libraryheaderselected")
        // Then go work on the sibling links (i.e. all except the one clicked)
        .siblings("a")
        // and reset them back to "libraryheader" status
        .removeClass("libraryheaderselected").addClass("libraryheader");
});
```

Once you do this you can forget about it; it works regardless of the number or ids of the links.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#libdiv a").on("click",function(){
  $(this).addClass("libraryheaderselected");
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("libraryheaderselected");
});
```

This will be more effective, because you won't have to remove a class from each link as a separate function, you can just do it as 2 methods. The first adds the class to what you clicked. The second removes the class from all of its siblings

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/ebECOR/1/edit

```
var links = $('#libdiv a');
$('#libdiv').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(links).removeClass('libraryheaderselected');
  $(this).addClass('libraryheaderselected');
});
```